# How I inform IIS there is a network map drive

Tags: asp.net

I have a Web Service running on IIS and I want to access a mapped network folder. How will I inform IIs for the mapping..

If I try to use the UNC path it outputs the error "current format not supported"...

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running Windows Server 2008 or Window 7 you can try to create a link to the UNC path.

```
mklink /D D:\IISFolder \\servername\sharediisfolder
```

The server share can then access D:\IISFolder.

If you're on older windows servers use

```
net use
```